# When did Poe and BB-8 meet?

Tags: star-wars, bb-8, poe-dameron

I've read a couple comics about Poe's parents in the Rebellion, and they didn't have BB-8 then, so he's not a family droid as far as I can tell.  Poe is incredibly close with him, though - do we know exactly when they met?  And is this in a canon piece, like a comic or book?

Answer (score 3):

[*Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: The Visual Dictionary*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_galactic_history#cite_note-BB-8_assignment-795) states that BB-8 was assigned to Poe Dameron four years before the Starkiller Incident, which "Star Wars: Galactic Atlas" dates to 34 ABY. Therefore, it could be found that BB-8 was assigned to Poe in 30 ABY.

Also, [*Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: The Visual Dictionary*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/BB-8#cite_note-Birth_year-2) states that BB-8 was manufactured five years before the Starkiller Incident, which "Star Wars: Galactic Atlas" dates to 34 ABY. Therefore, BB-8 was manufactured in 29 ABY.